# express.js static not recognising defined 'public' folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following dir setup;

`**app**
 **controllers**
  *index.server.controller.js*
 **models**
 **routes**
  *index.server.routes.js*
 **views**
  *index.ejs*
**config**
 **env**
 *config.js*
 *express.js*
**public**
 **css**
 **img**
  *logo.jpg*
 **js**
*server.js*
*package.json*`

Inside express.js, I'm loading the static directory using the following;

```
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '\\..\\public\\') - also attempted
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

I'm then serving index.ejs, which contains the following snippet;

```
<img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Logo"/>
```

However, this always results in a 404 being returned on the image itself.

`C:\nodejs>node horizontal/server
Localhost running on port 3000
GET / 304 13.763 ms - -
GET /img/logo.jpg 404 4.372 ms - 25`

As seen above, I've attempted giving a strict __dirname path (as I had to do with setting up the path to views, as seen below) - and also attempted just inserting public/img/logo.jpg in order to see it getting served up.

Views, as it works;

`app.set('views', __dirname+'\\..\\\\app\\views\\');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Would anyone have any ideas as to why express isn't seeing the public folder, or serving static content from it?

Note that my Dev env is Windows8.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the path module to do that.

```
var path = require('path');
```

With an app directory looking like below

[image]

You would just access the public folder like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, still no dice. 404 Still being returned as per Morgan.

Comment: Is public at the same level as the app folder or inside it? for my suggestion to work public needs to be inside the app folder, but from you description above, to me it seems they are at the same level